# is_page() function doesnt working

Tags: plugin-development, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style, wp-register-script

I'm trying to add these custom CSS and JS (written inside a custom plugin) only add to a specific page.

this is my code

```
<?php   

function randomAlphaNumeric($length) {
    $pool = array_merge(range(0,9), range('a', 'z'),range('A', 'Z'));
    $key='';
    for($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $key .= $pool[mt_rand(0, count($pool) - 1)];
    }
    return $key;
}



add_action('init', 'register_script');
function register_script(){
    if(is_page('page_title')) {
        wp_register_script( 'custom_js', plugins_url('/js/custom-js.js', __FILE__).'?random='.randomAlphaNumeric(5), array('jquery'));
        wp_register_style( 'new_style', plugins_url('/css/new-style.css', __FILE__).'?random='.randomAlphaNumeric(5), false, 'all');
    }
}


// use the registered jquery and style above
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_style');
function enqueue_style(){
    if(is_page('page_title')) {
        wp_enqueue_script('custom_js');
        wp_enqueue_style( 'new_style' );
    } 
}
```

but `is_page()` doesn't seem to work at all..
I tried to change it with **ID** and **SLUG**, but no success

**UPDATE**
replaced condition to check the page title, still doesnt work

```
add_action('init', 'register_script');
function register_script(){
    global $post;
    if($post->post_title == 'page_title') {
        wp_register_script( 'custom_js', plugins_url('/js/custom-js.js', __FILE__).'?random='.randomAlphaNumeric(5), array('jquery'));
        wp_register_style( 'new_style', plugins_url('/css/new-style.css', __FILE__).'?random='.randomAlphaNumeric(5), false, 'all');
    }
}


// use the registered jquery and style above
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_style');
function enqueue_style(){
    global $post;
    if($post->post_title == 'page_title') {
        wp_enqueue_script('custom_js');
        wp_enqueue_style( 'new_style' );
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `init` hook is too early — WordPress hasn't yet identified the queried object (post, category, etc.); hence the `is_page()` doesn't work there:

```php
add_action('init', 'register_script');
```

So for conditional tags/functions like `is_page()`, `is_single()`, etc. to work (i.e. return the proper result), you should use `wp` or a later hook:

```php
add_action('wp', 'whatever_function');
```

But for registering/enqueueing scripts and styles, you should always use the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook; so you would use this (and not the above):

```php
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_script');
```

*PS: Credits to @[huraji](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/93927/huraji) for his helpful comment.*

Comment: yes! thank you, would you please upvote my question, that might be someone else's question too

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to change the parameter from `page_title`to `page-slug` or `id`. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/#parameters
2. Let's try to register scripts in the same `enqueue_style()` function right before enqueueing them.

**Update**: My scope here was to encourage doing tries around different parameters for `is_page()` AND using the same function `enqueue_style()` hooked in `wp_enqueue_scripts` which is the ONLY suggested way to register/enqueue scripts.

Comment: Unlike a general forum, answers on Stack Exchange should be full and informative. Answers often don't lend themselves to "help along the way" methods of teaching but direct and informational. Comments are also not a place for extended discussion, [I've moved these to chat.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94058/discussion-on-answer-by-huraji-is-page-function-doesnt-working)